# PDF hangs system indefinitely

Tags: c#, pdfa

I am using O2S.Components.PDF4NET version 5.0.3.0 but certain PDF (which I found to be non PDF/A compliant) hangs the code forever at line **PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument(ms);**

```
        public static PDFDocument NewLicensedPDFDocument(Stream ms)
        {        
           PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument(ms);  
    
           doc.SerialNumber = "XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-AAAA";;
           return doc;
        }
```

PDF file opens easily on Adobe Acrobat Reader but fails validation on online PDF/A validator (https://www.pdf2go.com/validate-pdfa).

Error which online validator shows are
[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: What Stream are you passing into this method, how is it created?

Comment: @CSharpie - stream is basically pdf file which I converted into stream

Comment: @VaibhavDhasmana _"stream is basically pdf file"_ Details count, here. Be specific and add that info to your question. Comments _may_ be deleted. (At least they must be treated as if they could.)

Comment: Does the `PDFDocument` ctor have an overload to pass something like a "Leniant-Mode" switch? Although I would expect it to throw if it cannot deserialize a proper PDF...

Comment: Did you try another PDF library with that exact Document? Opening it in Acrobat Reader doesn't prove too much. I found it to be **_very_ forgiving** (and it must be to work halfway decently) back in the day when I had to deal with PDFs.

Comment: @Fildor - I cannot use any other library for it.
Thanks for your suggestion.
I'll check "Leniant-Mode" switch

Comment: What happens if you stream it to a file and then open the file using PDF4NET?

Comment: @Fildor - It do not have Leniant-Mode switch

Comment: @MatthewWatson- I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: @VaibhavDhasmana it is important to know how exactly you create the stream. One possilbe reason for the hang could be that its position is not at the start anymore so the reader is waiting for more data to finish reading the document.

Comment: @CSharpie - You were correct. Problem was in the creation of stream.